# Android Webview auto login to https website by setting token cookie

Tags: android, cookies, https, android-webview, ssl-certificate

What I am trying to achieve is to autologin to a https website by setting a token as a cookie.

( It works on android chrome browser but not in application webview )

Basically I am facing two issue while loading https url into web view with cookie set

**Issue 1**

I am getting following log message.

> Failed to validate the certificate chain, error:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found.

I tried overriding `onReceivedSslError` and called `handler.proceed();` as below.

```
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
    Log.d(TAG, "==> " + error.toString());
    handler.proceed();
}
```

But still I see white page ( I am assuming Its happening because of certificate issue. )

**Issue 2**

I have got a login url with me ( e.g https://www.abc.com/login.html )

What I am trying to achieve is auto login into web view by setting a cookie.

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(webView.getContext());
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);

String token = PreferenceHelper.loadTokenFromPreference(this);

String sessionCookie = "staging=" + token;

cookieManager.setCookie("https://www.abc.com/aaa/",
    sessionCookie);
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

SystemClock.sleep(1000);
```

But still I am not able to auto login.Rather I am seeing the white page.

What I am not sure now is exactly where I am making a mistake.

`cookieManager.setCookie` requires first argument as a url for which cookie needs to set,I am not sure exactly which url i need to give it ?

Can anyone suggest me the right approach to get it working ?

Thanks

Comment: It's rather weird that you know the cookie content but not the domain. Is this your website? If not how did you find out the cookie content?

Comment: @user3249477 I am setting a domain too. but still I am getting a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after searching for quite a while I finally got the solution.

I had to add following lines to get it working.

```
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Where is "appCachePath"?

Comment: @JigarShekh
      setAppCachePath(cacheDir)

Answer (score 7):

You can pass the Cookie as `HttpHeader` in `loadUrl` function of `WebView`.

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
String token = PreferenceHelper.loadTokenFromPreference(this);
String sessionCookie = "staging=" + token;
map.put("Cookie", sessionCookie);
webView.loadUrl(url, map);
```

Comment: What is PreferenceHelper? @Abhishek V

Comment: @JigarShekh i think its a SharedPreferences implementation class he made