# .NET MAUI WebView automatic login on basic auth webpage

Tags: .net, iis, webview, basic-authentication, maui

I have built a .NET MAUI app that displays some web pages in my company.

These web pages should not be accessed from outside of the application, so I added basic authentication to them (using IIS on Win2019).

Now, when someone tries to connect to the webpage with the URL, they are prompted to type in the credentials, so they can't see the contents.

I now want my MAUI app to be able to automatically authenticate in the web pages with hard-coded credentials, so users are able to see the contents ONLY when using the MAUI app.

I am using WebView for this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you managed to do it? I'm the same situation..

Answer (score 0):

If you utilize an access token for authentication (for example: show a members-only DotNetNuke web page in a Xamarin iOS app), the `WebViewRenderer` class can access that token and add an Authorization header to the web request.

You can refer to the following code:

```
protected NSMutableUrlRequest CreateAuthenticatedWebRequest()
{
    var headerKey = new NSString("Authorization");
    var headerValue = new NSString("Bearer " + App.User.AccessToken);
    var headersDictionary = new NSDictionary(headerKey, headerValue);

    UrlWebViewSource source = (Xamarin.Forms.UrlWebViewSource)Element.Source;
    var webRequest = new NSMutableUrlRequest(new NSUrl(_originalSourceUrlValue));
    webRequest.Headers = headersDictionary;

    return webRequest;
}
```

Then in the `OnElementChanged()` method, we can use the authenticated web request by code:

```
 Control.LoadRequest(CreateAuthenticatedWebRequest()).
```

Though it is on xamarin forms,but I believe the implementation is similar in maui.

You can also refer to this thread: [Android Webview auto login to https website by setting token cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25804725/android-webview-auto-login-to-https-website-by-setting-token-cookie).

Answer (score 0):

For those searching for how to do this with Bearer token, this worked for me in .NET MAUI

```
using System;
using NavistarOCCAppMAUI.Common;
#if IOS
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using WebKit;
#endif
namespace NavistarOCCAppMAUI.Handlers
{
    public class AuthenticatedWebView : WebView
    {
        static AuthenticatedWebView()
        {
            Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WebViewHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(IWebView.Source), async (handler, view) =>
            {
                if (view is AuthenticatedWebView webView)
                {
                    var url = webView.Url!;
                    var token =await  LoginSecureStorage.Instance.GetAuthAccessToken();
#if ANDROID
                var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    ["Authorization"] = token
                };
                handler.PlatformView.LoadUrl(url, headers);
#elif IOS
            var webRequest = new NSMutableUrlRequest(new NSUrl(url));
            var headerKey = new NSString("Authorization");
            var headerValue = new NSString(token);
            var dictionary = new NSDictionary(headerKey, headerValue);
            webRequest.Headers = dictionary;
            var webViewDelegate = new WebViewDelegate();
            handler.PlatformView.NavigationDelegate = webViewDelegate;

            handler.PlatformView.LoadRequest(webRequest as NSUrlRequest);
#else
            throw new NotImplementedException();
#endif
            }

        });
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TokenProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Token", typeof(string), typeof(AuthenticatedWebView), "");

    public string? Token
    {
        get => GetValue(TokenProperty) as string;
        set => SetValue(TokenProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty UrlProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Url", typeof(string), typeof(AuthenticatedWebView), "");
    public string? Url
    {
        get => GetValue(UrlProperty) as string;
        set => SetValue(UrlProperty, value);
    }
}
#if IOS
///on iOS tell WkWebview to use credentials
public class WebViewDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
{
    public override void DidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge(WKWebView webView, NSUrlAuthenticationChallenge challenge, Action<NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSUrlCredential> completionHandler)
    {
        completionHandler(NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, new NSUrlCredential(challenge.ProtectionSpace.ServerSecTrust));

        return;
    }
}
#endif
}
```